# How do expand.grid and rep work together to show all the combinations of outcomes?

Tags: r

I am using `rep` and `expand.grid` with `lists`, but the output is not what I expected. The documentation isn't clear on how `expand.grid` works with `lists`. Could someone explain how the two functions work together?

`rep` replicates the elements of a vector `x`

```r
x <- c(0, 1)
rep(x, 2)
# 0 1 0 1
```

so it replicates vector/list elements.

However, when I run it like this:

```r
rep(list(x),2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0 1
```

Why are there two repeat elements in two different entries of the list? I was expecting this to yield a `list` with 1 element containing `0 1 0 1`.

Also, using `expand.grid` on the vector `0 1 0 1` gives:

```r
expand.grid(c(0, 1, 0, 1))
#  Var 1
#1     0
#2     1
#3     0
#4     1
```

However, using `expand.grid` on the above list gives:

```r
expand.grid(rep(list(x), 2))
#  Var1 Var2
#1    0    0
#2    1    0
#3    0    1
#4    1    1
```

How does this work?

Comment: Hi, what code are you using here exactly? Because from the text it is not entirely clear what you are referring to. Also, do you understand what the `expand.grid` function and the `rep` functions do separately?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, I hope the edits to the question have made it clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Question 1: Why does `rep(list(x),2)` yield a list with 2 elements?**

The best way to think of a list (for now) is that it's a vector whose elements can be anything. When you run `list(x)`, you create a list where the first element is itself a vector, namely `0 1`. When you enter a list to `rep`, it will simply replicate the elements of the list as it would for a vector. So:

```r
rep(list(x), 2)
```

Replicates the elements of `list(x)`. Since it is a list of length 1, it will yield a list of length 2. Keep in mind that in this process I never talked about the CONTENT of the elements. If you want to replicate those, then you first have to grab them from the list:

```r
rep(list(x)[[1]], 2)
# [1] 0 1 0 1
```

---

**Question 2: So why does `expand.grid(rep(list(x), 2))` not also output a list?**

That's because `expand.grid` was written to work in two ways:

1. Supply each vector/factor as a separate argument
2. Put all vectors/factors in a list and supply that as the only argument

Since you are supplying one list, `expand.grid` will then look at the CONTENT of each element, and apply `expand.grid` across the elements. Effectively, you are calling:

```r
expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1))
```

And indeed, as soon as we supply TWO arguments, it returns a more expected behavior (i.e. all combinations of all elements of the two lists):

```r
expand.grid(list(x, x + 1), list(x + 2, x + 3))
#  Var1 Var2
#1 0, 1 2, 3
#2 1, 2 2, 3
#3 0, 1 3, 4
#4 1, 2 3, 4
```

---